# Jquery show/hide multiple divs with 3 different navbars

Tags: jquery, hide, show, html

I was using code based on the following jsfiddle to show/hide divs on my webpage:
http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/420/

It works on one part of my page, in the first navbar. There are two other navbars that I need to account for, and they use the same code. Example...

```
    $('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
    /* $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); */
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
    });

    $('.showSingle').first().click();
```

and

```
<div id="headnav">
<ul>
<li><a href ="#" class="showSingle" data-target="1">&bull;&nbsp;HOME</a> </li>
<li><a href ="#" class="showSingle" data-target="2">&bull;&nbsp;ABOUT US</a> </li>
<li><a href ="#" class="showSingle" data-target="3">&bull;&nbsp;CONTACT</a> </li>
<li><a href ="#" class="showSingle" data-target="4">&bull;&nbsp;WHERE TO BUY</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href ="#" class="showSingle" data-target="5">&bull;&nbsp;PIPE TOBACCO</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href ="#" class="showSingle" data-target="6">KENTUCKY SELECT</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#" class="showSingle" data-target="7">BUCKHORN</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href ="#" class="showSingle" data-target="8">&bull;&nbsp;ORGANIC TOBACCO</a></li>
    <li><a href ="#" class="showSingle" data-target="9">&bull;&nbsp;CIGARETTE TOBACCO</a></li>
    <li><a href ="#" class="showSingle" data-target="10">&bull;&nbsp;FILTER CIGARS</a></li>
    <li><a href ="#" class="showSingle" data-target="11">&bull;&nbsp;E-CIGARETTES</a></li>
</ul>
```

etc... For a more detailed list, visit www.rcgraphicsstudio.com/ecryo. You'll notice that the header and the footer are both fixed to the top and bottom, so I'm hoping that's not what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your given page (www.rcgraphicsstudio.com/ecryo) the jQuery is fine. The problem you have is your div5 through div14 are all within div4 in the DOM. div1 - div4 are on the same level and then you nested the rest within 4. Fix that, and your page will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You #div5 to 11 elements are actually nested in you #div4 element. So when you click on the link "target=5" you hide the parent elements of the div you want to show.

Comment: Thank you! All of you gave basically the same answer, and that worked. You are all terrific.

Answer (score 0):

I went to your site and it looks like the problem there is that every subnav element is contained in `#div4` so if `$(this).data('target')) > 4` you need to both show `#div4` and `$('#div' + $(this).data('target'))`.